# storing NSData in an array

Tags: ios, base64, nsdata

I stored decoded base64 image in NSData and then want to make an array of it. I used the below code but its not working. Please help!

```
NSMutableArray * searchResultsImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (int i=0; i<searchResults.count; i++)
    {
        NSString *images = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:3];
        [Base64 initialize];
        NSData *data = [Base64 decode:images];
        [searchResultsImages addObject:data];
        NSLog(@"searchResultsImages: %@", searchResultsImages);
    }
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Check the `searchResults`, maybe it's empty

Comment: After the execution of `NSData *data = [Base64 decode:images];` data is nil. Nothing goes in data however, I'm getting encoded string in `images`.

Comment: @Levi `searchResults` are not empty. I'm able to get encoded string in `images`.

Comment: @AyanSengupta I'm getting nil in `data`. However, `images` contains encoded string.

Comment: That means your decoder is not being able to decode your base64 encoded images. If you are on iOS 7 you can use its native base64 decoder for that purpose if somehow a third party decoder fails.

Comment: @AyanSengupta I tried native iOS7 `NSData *decodedData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:images options:0];
            UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageWithData:decodedData];` and again I'm getting nil for decoded data.

Comment: So it essentially means the encoder is not encoding/sending data in a valid base64 format. Please check the encoding/downloading process.